# F# - how to turn a list into a list of list?

Tags: list, f#

I was wondering how to make a list such as

```
[1;2;3;4]
```

and turn it into

```
[[1];[2];[3];[4]]
```

I was thinking of using List.init but that didn't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[1;2;3;4] |> List.map (fun i -> [i])
```

Comment: A tiny bit tidier looking would be using `List.singleton` instead of the lambda.

Comment: Didn't know that one. `[1;2;3;4] |> List.map List.singleton`.

Every time I look at a new problem, however straightforward, I find a new feature in the language

Comment: Reduce it even more with: "[1..4]". Example:  [1..4] |> List.map List.singleton

Comment: I find the lambda visually easier to parse though. You see that it lifts i to [i].

Comment: It's fewer characters as well. :)